# Swift: load new SKScene over original GameScene? (Still keep GameScene underneath?)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

alright so I'm creating a sprite kit game in Swift and I need to present a new `SKScene` OVER (as in the new scene would have a clear background so you can still see `GameScene` underneath) my original `GameScene`.

I tried doing this multiple ways, originally transitioning to a view controller which in turn was supposed to present the new `SKScene` the way apple did with `GameScene` and `GameViewController`, however all I got was a gray screen. None of the code for the new `SKScene` was executed and I couldn't add any `skspritenodes` or whatever.

So now I've partially succeeded by transitioning to a view controller which transitions to the new `SKScene` (named `GameOverScene`) like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        (self.view as! SKView).presentScene(GameOverScene(size: self.view.bounds.size))

    }
```

And then in `GameOverScene` I have:

```
    let saveMeBtn = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //Do stuff in scene
        println("it works!")

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.clearColor()

        saveMeBtn.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5)
        saveMeBtn.setScale(1)
        addChild(saveMeBtn)

    }

}
```

And it seems to be working, however there are 2 problems:

1. "it works! is printed to the console and I'm able to change the background color, but I can't add sprite nodes or anything. For example I can't see `saveMeBtn`
2. Even when I set the background to `clearColor()`, I can't see GameScene underneath. I just get a black screen.

What am I doing wrong here? How would I load in another `SKScene` over `GameScene` and still see `GameScene`?

Comment: You can create a heads-up display or an overlay over the current scene with one or more `SKNode`s. You don't need to present a new scene to do that.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding SpriteKit is optimized to only render presented scenes and SKViews are only able to present one scene at a time.

I could be wrong but it will know when the UIViewController with the SKView/SKScene isn't top most and it will not render or update. It would be similar to when you do a push segue to another VC with a SKView. If it continued to render it you would get very bad performance, so SpriteKit stops rendering and updating SKViews that are not visible.

Your best bet is to create a SKNode or SKSpriteNode subclass for it if you want your game to show up underneath. You can size it how you want and still see the rest of the scene under it. If it were me I would add a SKNode called GameOver add any Sprites I need to that and then slide the game over screen up.

Hopefully that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just load it with a reference node 
Use the appropriate path to point to new scene. 
If u want to access physics it's better to add them with enumeration after loading the scene.

Gamescene gets unloaded due to ARC since it's not visible it gets discarded